# Calling 2 curried functions onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a checkbox which calls a curried function and works fine when changing the checkstate as below

```
const FirstCurriedFunc = (id) => () => {
  //does something
}

return (
   <input type="checkbox" checked={true} onChange={FirstCurriedFunc(id)} />
)
```

However when I try to call two curried Functions onChange neither function executes as expected even though they both work when called individually as above.

```
const SecondCurriedFunc = (id) => () => {
  //does something
}

const BothCurriedFuncs = (id) => () => {
  FirstCurriedFunc(id);
  SecondCurriedFunc(id);
}

return (
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={BothCurriedFuncs(id)} />  // neither function executes
);
```

Can anyone explain why this is/provide a way to call both functions onChange?

Comment: I think you're confusing Function Currying vs. Partial Application.

Comment: Hint: your `FirstCurriedFunc` returns a function, but you're failing to invoke it.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of how I should be typing it instead?

Comment: Better idea: use your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually invoke both functions in `BothCurriedFuncs`:

```
const BothCurriedFuncs = (id) => () => {
    FirstCurriedFunc(id)();
    SecondCurriedFunc(id)();
}
```

or, maybe cleaner, use a helper function to create a composition:

```
let compose = (...fns) => () => fns.reduceRight((x, f) => f(x), null)


const BothCurriedFuncs = (id) => compose(SecondCurriedFunc(id), FirstCurriedFunc(id))
```